# upgraded to "Xcode 10" and now my Source Editor extension is not displayed under the Editor menu

Tags: xcode9, xcode10, xcode-extension

I opened my Source Editor Extension I created in Xcode 9 in Xcode 10.0. I tried to debug it but it doesn't show up under the Editor menu. It's not listed in System Preferences either. I'm thinking that I need to update a setting somewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried to create a simple test project, and even that didn't work. No item under the Editor menu or in System Preferences.

Comment: I can't even get third party extensions too work. I tried getting LineX from the Mac App store which use to work but now doesn't.

Comment: I have the same problem.. Can't find any solution anywhere... I spent hours on this

Comment: Try this. Download “find any file” from Mac App Store. It ca search everyday nook and cranny on your drive. Search for your apps name using contains. Delete everything except your project and source then reboot. Rebuild and try again. Don’t forget to check it in System Extensions.

Comment: Anyone found solution ? I was trying this test application.